# While IFS loop continue when less than 5 terminals open

Tags: linux, bash

I have loop function:

```
while IFS='|' read -r keyword; do
      xterm -e "echo -ne '\e[8;5;60t'; program -command"
done < ./filename
```

I need to open only 5 terminals with `program -command` but when one terminal do the job and close then loop should start open again until 5 opened windows.

I try

```
[ $( jobs | wc -l ) -ge 5 ] && wait
```

But after one is done job only 4 is open and this wait to the last one until is open and start again 5 times.

Maybe some can modify this scirpt to work

```
while [ `ps -p ${pid1},${pid2} | wc -l` < 5 ]
do
  sleep 1
done
```

This scirpt run every one second new terminal...

```
while IFS='|' read -r keyword; do
      xterm -e "echo -ne '\e[8;5;60t'; program -command" &
      sleep 1
done < ./filename
```

But i need something to check if there are opened 5x terminals if not then run loop one more time.

```
while IFS='|' read -r keyword; do
      xterm -e "echo -ne '\e[8;5;60t'; program -command"
      # Script to block loop until less than 5 terminal are open
      while [ `ps -p ${pid1},${pid2} | wc -l` < 5 ]
      do
        echo "There is less than 5 terminals opened"
      done
done < ./filename
```

I found something like this, how to modify this?

```
while [  $(ps -ef | grep KEYWORD | grep -v grep | wc -l) -gt 0 ]; do
sleep 1
done
```

I made script

```
        child_count=$(($(pgrep --parent $$ | wc -l) - 1))
        if [ "$child_count" -lt "5" ]; then
            echo "Opened terminals: $child_count"
        else [ "$child_count" -ge "5" ]
            echo "Too many termianls: $child_count"; wait
        fi
```

But still is waiting until all finished, this should check every 10 sec if one terminal is less than 5

I found solution:

```
        check_processes(){
            while true; do
                child_count=$(($(pgrep --parent $$ | wc -l) - 1))
                if [ "$child_count" -lt "5" ]; then
                    echo "Opened terminals: $child_count"
                break
                else [ "$child_count" -ge "5" ]
                    echo "Too many termianls: $child_count"; sleep 10; check_processes
                fi
            done
            }
        check_processes
```

Comment: Are you asking how to have five terminal windows always open, such that when one is closed a new one is created?

Comment: Yes, thats right

Comment: It looks like [xyproblem](http://xyproblem.info/). Why don't you use [parallel](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/)?

Comment: i use loop variable for other commands like echo or other program parallel can read only for one program one line another parallel for echo with be diffrent variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code segment will create five `xterm` windows. As you kill them off another one will be spawned.

```
#!/bin/bash
#
pids=()

# Eternal loop
while :
do
    if [[ ${#pids[@]} -lt 5 ]]
    then
        # Start another process
        xterm &
        pid=$!

        # Save process id
        pids+=($pid)
    else
        # We have enough so wait for (at least) one to die
        wait -n

        # Reap old process ids
        oldpids=("${pids[@]}")
        pids=()
        n=0
        while [[ $n -lt ${#oldpids[@]} ]]
        do
            pid=${oldpids[$n]}
            [[ -n "$pid" ]] && kill -0 $pid 2>/dev/null && pids+=($pid)
            n=$((n+1))
        done
    fi
done
```